# @sendGrid - 403 'Forbidden Access' Error from a authenticated sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Stackoverflow newbie here with a problem regarding testing sendGrid Emails - I've verified my sender email and attempted to send an email using my nodeJS application however I still run into this error:

"Error: The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. " (Taken from the response body of the error)

The images below show the verified sender email in use.

```js
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const msg = {
    to: 'jordanlyn.98@hotmail.com',
    from: 'jordanlyn.98@hotmail.com', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
    subject: "Enquiry",
    text: 'Hello',
 };

//ES8
sgMail
.sennd(msg)
.then(()=> {
  console.log('Email sent')
  })
```

[image: Proof of Sender Verification]

P.S I originally thought it was the access rights on the API key itself, I went into the setting and changed it to full access to avoid any rights issues however, the response body of the error states the sender is not verified.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow! One thing I'd recommend for sharing code, instead of images, you can use the 'code' block feature in the editor (or hit ctrl + k).

As far as the request, from their documentation everything looks correct to me. My only guess is there might be a delay between verification and when you can actually send? Other than that, may want to reach out to SendGrid support too.

Comment: Thanks for the response @David, I managed to fix the issue, I wasn't running 'source <envfile>' to load it into the terminal.